# Referencing a Schema's table batch/perl

Tags: database, perl, batch-file

I just came across this when looking into someone else code.

Say there is this schema called Books that has a table call Genres...whenever this schema and table is being used on a script, such as batch/perl it was originally Books..Genres

question is, should it stay like this or changed to Books.Genres?  and what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I rarely work outside my default schema and thus rarely ever list the schema name in my SQL statements.  Having said that, there are rare occasions when I do need to access more than one schema and only a single dot is used to separate the schema name from the table name.  I checked both DB2 and Oracle: neither even allow a double dot.  So, unless they are manipulating the SQL in some manner (e.g. maybe the code is processed in a template), SQL statements with a double dot should not work.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't allow a double dot as separator either; so unless they're preprocessing the SQL in some way as kjpires suggested, this is likely an error. Does the code work?